# Open Babel: conversion to SMILES. How to delete H?

Tags: cheminformatics

OpenBabel is a convenient converter between different chemical formats.
If I convert to SMILES, however, although I checked the option "Delete hydrogens (make implicit)".
I still have `H` in the SMILES codes.

[image]

It's the same with the command line. It also does not remove `H`.

```
obabel.exe Molecule.log -osmi -d
```

I still have, e.g. `...C[CH]C...` in the SMILES.
Of course, I could replace all occurrences of `[CH]` by `C`, but I'm not sure whether I would mess up the SMILES and/or the molecule.
How can I get rid of the hydrogen? Why is it actually in there? Did I miss any other options during conversion?

Comment: Provide some example molecules maybe?

Comment: When I do `obabel -:"[CH4]" -ofpt -o SMILES` the output is `C`, so I'm not sure why the command line (at least) isn't working for you.

Comment: @Curt F., right, an example is missing. I cannot place the Gaussian file here. Which exact section in the Gaussian output file (start/end keywords) is actually extracted by OpenBabel?
Well, for a demo try caffeine `CN1C=NC2=C1C(=O)N(C(=O)N2C)C` which gets `CH3` drawn. But in the meantime I found another option in OpenBabel "do not draw terminal C(and attached H) explicitely". With this it looks fine.
However, with conversion from Gaussian output file I also once got two double bonds to Nitrogen. I'm not a chemist, but this sounds wrong to me. I need to dig out an example which I can show.